# R code to modify strings in column not working in Power BI/Query

Tags: r, powerbi

I have a query that combines multiple excel files and final step looks like this:

```
     = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, 
        {"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}, {"Path", type text}, 
        {"AstType", type text}, {"AstName", type text}, {"SYMBOL", type text}, 
        {"ISO", type text}, {"MValue", type number}, {"Weight", type number}, 
        {"#Sec", Int64.Type}, {"Flag", Int64.Type}, {"RunDate", type date}})
```

Now I am trying to run some R code:

```
dataset$Path = gsub('A Fund.', '', dataset$Path)
dataset$Path = gsub('Fund.', '', dataset$Path)
```

But this is returning an empty table. I am always ignoring the Privacy level settings. How can this be fixed?

Comment: need to see the original data... can you provide with `dput(dataset)`

Comment: I certainly can provide some data, but I feel like the issue is not with R. I have created a small sample of the table and tried to run this code directly in R. IT works with no issue ...